# Why was an image of Glaurung set into the Helm of Hador?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

So it says in *The Children of Húrin* by Tolkien (and his son) that the Helm of Hador — also called the Dragon of Dor-lómin — was made by the smith Telchar, who had, ‘in defiance’, put ‘a gilded image of Glaurung the dragon’ on the crest.

It also says that *‘the hearts of the host of Hithlum were uplifted when they saw it towering high amid the battle’*.

Why, though? Wasn’t Glaurung one of the most potent symbols of Morgoth’s power?

Comment: At the time the helm was made, Glaurung's only appearance had been as an immature dragon who was driven back by the Elves. If anything, he was a symbol of the ability to overcome Morgoth's power.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you answered your own question: ***defiance*** and also ***encouragement***.

Why do Christians wear crucifixes, a potent symbol of state power over life and death?

Why do members of ethnic groups often call one another by a term of abuse used by another group?

They do so, in some way, to thumb their noses at something beyond their power to control or change.  In this case, as you say: *‘the hearts of the host of Hithlum were uplifted when they saw it towering high amid the battle*.

Comment: "You think you are tough? I wear the heads of my enemies on my chest as a crest!"

"You think you are tough? I wear the skulls of my enemies as my helmet!"

https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_of_Bones

Comment: @jo1storm Also, ["Bring me wine in the skull of an enemy!" on Oglaf](https://www.oglaf.com/skulls/).